# binding an object to the global scope

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var myVar = (function (window) {    

    myobj = {};

    myobj.boo = function() {
        alert('hi');
    };

    window.myVar = myobj;

})(window);

myVar.boo();
```

Why don't I get back the alert when I call myVar.boo() ? I've created an anonymous self-executing function and fed in the window object. Inside that I have another object with a method assigned to it. I then assign the global myVar variable to this obj. This should provide an alias to the my myobj object. However when I call the function I get an Cannot call method 'boo' of undefined error

Comment: `myobj.boo()` will do it unfortunately. *Don't forget about `var`*.

Comment: @elduderino: You are not returning anything to the variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should either remove the first assignment

```
var myVar =
```

as you are replacing myVar value to the return of a function that doesn't return anything,

or more likely return myVar from your function, instead of assigning from inside the closure:

```
var myVar = (function() {
  var myobj = {};

  myobj.boo = function() {
      alert('hi');
  };

  return myobj;
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `myVar` with an `undefined` value here. When you are initializing it its calling the anonymous function. And stores the returned value. But the function does not return anything. So nothing is assigned to `myVar`.  Even though you added `window.myVar = myobj`, it gets overrided when the function is finished.